# AGM Snazzy window size

Tags: angular, google-maps, infowindow

Is there a way to resize the snazzy info window in AGM? it is quite big for the map in my project.

here is my code :

```
                        <agm-marker
                            *ngFor="let marker of markers"
                            [latitude]="marker.bldg_long" 
                            [longitude]="marker.bldg_lat"
                            [iconUrl]="'assets/icon1.gif'">
                            <agm-snazzy-info-window 
                                [isOpen]="true" 
                                [latitude]="marker.bldg_long" 
                                [longitude]="marker.bldg_lat"
                                [maxWidth]="800" 
                                [closeWhenOthersOpen]="false"

                                backgroundColor="orange">
                                <ng-template>
                                    {{ marker.bldg_name }}
                                </ng-template>
                            </agm-snazzy-info-window>
                        </agm-marker>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change maxWidth in your code and set maxHeight and padding as wanted. 
Like this:

```
<agm-snazzy-info-window 
    [maxWidth]="600" 
    maxHeight="200px" 
    padding="15px 15px 0 0">
        <!--content-->
</agm-snazzy-info-window>
```